# Unity + Firebase + iOS = error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I need a help please.
Unity 5.6
Firebase sdk added (components FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage and FirebaseRemoteConfig.unitypackage)

And i have an errors in xCode.

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libAnalytics.a(analytics_ios_9d78633b4a8aa3f633f0c68e9cb50efd.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalyticsConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libAnalytics.a(analytics_ios_9d78633b4a8aa3f633f0c68e9cb50efd.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libApp.a(app_ios_c76c7d869e568a9b561ea55e25a7dcc0.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libApp.a(app_ios_c76c7d869e568a9b561ea55e25a7dcc0.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRRemoteConfigSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_53531e292e202c8e07f4ebe5b73bbec1.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRRemoteConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_53531e292e202c8e07f4ebe5b73bbec1.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I don't know about Cocoapods, but i think Unity must do all my work.
I used instructions from this page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

I can't even understand what does this error means - xCode can't find Firebase Anlitics module? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use some `code highlighting` in your question.. it's pretty hard to read it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an image to Firebase in iOS and I get an error: Firebase.Storage.StorageException: No object exists at the desired reference
I tested it on the mac very well, but not on the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Well after all i fixed this by manually adding firebase frameworks from official site into assets folder

`\Assets\Plugins\iOS\Firebase`

And i don't know why unity can't do it by itself.

Thanks for everybody!